# The type "unknown" cannot be assigned to the type "boolean"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
        if (queueEntry) {
            this.inProcess.push(queueEntry);
            try {
                await callback(queueEntry);
                this.inProcess = this.inProcess.filter(queueTmp => queueTmp.id !== queueEntry.id).concat([]);
                this.successfull.push(queueEntry);
            } catch (error) {
                queueEntry.error = error;
                this.inProcess = this.inProcess.filter(queueTmp => queueTmp.id !== queueEntry.id).concat([]);
                this.failed.push(queueEntry);
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
    }
```

typescript version :"4.3.5"
issue : The type "unknown" cannot be assigned to the type "boolean"
p.s : i get the this issue because my catch parameter (error) is unknown and i can't parse it ,

Comment: The error message tells us that `queueEntry.error` is a `boolean`, so presumably from the name it's meant to indicate that an error occurred by having a `true`. So instead of `queueEntry.error = error;`, use `queueEntry.error = true;`. Why are you trying to assign the unknown `error` to it instead?

Comment: Side note: There's no point to the `.concat([])` you have on the end of your `filter` calls. What were you trying to do with it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks a lot it works like charm , i found that typescript version 4.4.2 make this issue too , i just changed the typescript version on my Vs code to 4.3.5 it works again ,regarding the .concat you are right, it has no sense , thanks a lot  for the notes

Answer (score 1):

You need to type the exception of the catch block like this:

```
catch(error:unknown) { //Typescript only lets the exceptions be typed as any or unknown
```

But further in the catch block you can check and only if type of error is `boolean`, assign it to `queueEntry.error`

```
if (typeof error==="boolean") queueEntry.error=error
```